# Angular "ng generate component" Duplicating Component

Tags: angular

For some reason since upgrading from Angular 13 to Angular 15, when I type:
`ng g c SomeComponent`
Angular duplicates the component, creating duplicate files. This happens 100% of the time. A second weird thing (not sure if it's related), but it does not add `ngOnInit()` to the components either.
[image: ng generate component output]

Comment: Hi @David, im working with angular15 but no problem on creating new components

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I am working with Angular 16 and recently ran into this problem as well. It also does the same thing when trying to generate services for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer was upgrading. Someone already answered this, but the answer is not here. It was a bug in Angular. In the short term I just deleted the duplicate files. But when I upgraded the problem went away.